# Eclipse : How to copy contents of project explorer to clipboard using eclipse copy

Tags: eclipse, command, contextmenu

In project explorer I am trying to implement a custom paste command for which I wish to use the eclipse copy to copy the contents to clipboard and then access it on my custom paste command . After copy I tried to get the contents from clipboard but the clipboard was empty.

I tried to add the handler for copy with the same command id as the Eclipse Copy command but I get the conflicting handlers error .

What is the right way to reuse the eclipse command id's and the handlers for those commands ?

Here is the code

For my custom paste I am not using the Paste from eclipse , I have created a new context menu Paste Objects by adding a new command .
I have added the handler : PasteObjectsHandler for the command which extends AbstractHandler .

Command

```xml
  <command
        categoryId="org.eclipse.ui.category.edit"
        description="%pasteobjectscommand.description_xmsg"
        id="com.test.pasteobjectscommand"
        name="%pasteobjectscommand.name_xtit">
    </command>
```

Handler

```xml
   <handler
        class="com.test.PasteObjectsHandler"
        commandId=" com.test.pasteobjectscommand "> 
    </handler>
```

Handler class

```java
   public class PasteObjectsHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) {


    Clipboard clipBoard = new Clipboard(Display.getDefault());
    LocalTransfer instance = LocalTransfer.getInstance();
    IResource clipboardData = (IResource) clipBoard.getContents(instance);

}
```

And in the handler I try to access the clipboard in the execute method . And I get null here .

Comment: Project Explorer already has a Copy handler which you can't easily override. How are you deal with the Paste?

Comment: I am adding a new context menu for paste(PasteObjects), and not disturbing the existing eclipse paste.

Comment: Show us the code dealing with the paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the paste handler you should use something like:

```java
TransferData[] availableTypes = clipboard.getAvailableTypes();

Transfer transfer = ResourceTransfer.getInstance();

if (isAvailable(transfer, availableDataTypes)) {
   return (IResource[])clipboard.getContents(transfer);
}


private static boolean isAvailable(Transfer transfer, TransferData[] availableDataTypes) {
    for (int i= 0; i < availableDataTypes.length; i++) {
        if (transfer.isSupportedType(availableDataTypes[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You might also need to check `FileTransfer` and `TextTransfer`.

Comment: Don't forget to Accept good answers - [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)